# Jekyll Bootstrap requires jquery on every page

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jekyll, cdn

Currently building a small personal site using Jekyll and Bootstrap, currently facing an issue where when refreshing the browser, Bootstrap jQuery works meaning that I can use the responsive navbar toggle button to change to a different page.

Once I have clicked on another menu item I get taken to that page however jQuery then stops working and I get the following error in the console:

Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery(anonymous function) @ bootstrap.min.js:6

Refresh the page once or twice and it works again, click on another menu item and the same error occurs.

I have checked that jQuery is loaded before the Bootstrap file and this is all correct.

Comment: A repository url can be useful to spot your problem.

Comment: Chances are ur loading jquery from a cdn , network connectivity issue. But to get a more precise answer , please provide a link to the page or demo where we can look help.

Comment: Hi @Shail here is an older version of what I am working on which has the same issue only difference in the current version is more pages and work done to some other pages. https://github.com/Dansmithyy/dansmeuktheme/tree/master/

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you're accessing the website in a browser that doesn't support the async attribute for external scripts? http://caniuse.com/#feat=script-async